# Adjust a field in a SimpleForm's value

Tags: react-admin

I have a React Admin Edit form with a field which by default doesn't exist in the record. I could manually type it in, save it and it would work. However I wish to retrieve the value of this field programmatically when a user clicks a button then adjust it.

I use a useMutation hook to access a custom API which performs an expensive operation and returns a result for the field. I only want to perform this operation when the user clicks a button.
So inside a Edit form I have this field called `key` I want to apply the data from this useMutation hook to it.

```
export const PostEdit = (props) => (
  <Edit title={<PostTitle />} {...props}>
    <SimpleForm>
      <TextInput disabled source="id" />
      <RetrieveKey />
      <TextInput source="key" />
    </SimpleForm>
  </Edit>
);
```

The RetrieveKey button is like this

```
const RetrieveKey = ({ record }) => {
  const [retrieve, { loading }] = useMutation(
    {
      type: "retrieveKey",
      resource: "posts",
      payload: { id: record.id }
    },
    {
      onSuccess: ({ data }) => {
        if (data) {
          // Set the key field here.
        } else {
          console.log("No Key");
        }
      },
      onFailure: (error) => console.log("Error");
    }
  );
  return (
    <Button
      onClick={retrieve}
      disabled={loading}
      label={"Retrieve Key"}
    ></Button>
  );
};
```

I have looked through the various Form Hooks but can't find anything documented which would let me accomplish this.
Note, I don't want to instantly call the UpdateMethod or this would be trivial and I could use the DataProvider useUpdate to call it. Instead I want to prefill in the form for the user from the responsed key.
A codesandbox is provided here: https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-firefly-k13g7?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to access the underlying React-Final-Form API in order to edit the form.

The React-Admin Docs briefly touch on it here: https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Inputs.html#linking-two-inputs

So in this case I needed to use the useForm hook which then allowed me to update the form value.

```
const RetrieveKey = ({ record }) => {
  const form = useForm();
  const [retrieve, { loading }] = useMutation(
    {
      type: "retrieveKey",
      resource: "posts",
      payload: { id: record.id }
    },
    {
      onSuccess: ({ data }) => {
        console.log(form);
        
        if (data) {
          form.change("key", data);
        } else {
          console.log("No Key found");
        }
      },
      onFailure: (error) =>  console.log("Error");
    }
  );
  return (
    <Button
      onClick={retrieve}
      disabled={loading}
      label={"Retrieve Key"}
    ></Button>
  );
};
```